# IndexedDB with inline keys, polyfill to Web SQL, how to get key to allow update?

Tags: key, indexeddb, web-sql, polyfills

I have been unable to update a record when using the IndexedDB shim to Web SQL: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim

I am also using IDBWrapper: https://github.com/jensarps/IDBWrapper

Despite me using these libraries, I believe that my question might still be relevant, and I might still be advised appropriately, as it could be related just to general usage of IndexedDB and Web SQL

I am implementing IndexedDB storage, using inline keys.

```
_store = new IDBStore({
    storeName: 'person',
    keyPath: 'PersonId',
    autoIncrement: true,
    onStoreReady: _loadPersons
});
```

When I save an object to the store...

```
_store.put(person, _loadPersons);
```

...it will generate an auto-incrementing key, and then store this key value automatically on the object, named after the 'keyPath' property, in this case *PersonId*.

This works great. If I inspect the IndexedDB storage in Chrome, there are 2 columns. Key (Key path: 'PersonId') and Value (containing the object).

If I want to update the same object, I just make sure it contains a property named *PersonId*, and has the same value as they key I want to save, and it will update.

However, when using the IndexedDB shim which saves to Web SQL (e.g. in Safari for Windows, or mobile browsers), when I load the objects in they do not contain the *PersonId* property at all.

For reference, the `_loadPersons` callback is as follows:

```
_loadPersons = function () {
    _store.getAll(_setPersons);
};
```

If I inspect the Web SQL storage in Safari, there are 3 columns, key (which is in the format 1-0, 1-1, 1-2), inc (1, 2, 3) and value (which contains a JSON string of the object, missing the *PersonId* property.

I'm not sure how the inline keys feature works in IndexedDB, but it seems that whatever it does, it doesn't happen in Web SQL.

**How should I be referring to objects that I want to update, when using this approach?**

**Should I just use out-of-line keys?**

**Has anyone else implemented an IndexedDB -> Web SQL structure, if so what libraries did they use and did they come across this issue?**

UPDATE:

I have looked at the code behind an example of the Indexed DB JQuery plugin using the IndexedDB polyfill: http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/example/.
 However this example all the items already have an 'itemId', and it doesn't have any logic for adding new items, just moving existing items to different places (cart, wishlist), so I can only assume that this approach would be an 'out-of-line keys' approach.

UPDATE 2:

The way I resolved my situation, to enable me to work with IndexedDBShim and IDBWrapper, is detailed as an answer below. However probably the better solution is to ditch these two libraries and try something else.

Comment: I am experiencing this very same problem. I created an [issue in Github](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/issues/122) to track it. For the record: this does not happen with the [facebook polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill), but that one is a project with much less activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try my own open source library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home It has full shimming from WebSQL to IndexedDB including inline/outline/autoIncrement/compound/multiEntry key. There is [qunit test](http://dev.yathit.com/test/test_all.html) as well.

Edit, additional answers:

> if you used autoIncrementing inline keys, and you didn't store the timeStamp on the object manually, would Web SQL know which object to update?

While autoIncrement inline key is used and a record value don't have primary key, it is considered as a new object (and it is). Note: Sqlite also has concept of auto increment numeric primary key.

> Also it looks like in Web SQL every time you refresh the demo makes a new store?

Nop. If a new store is created on page refresh, it is not database.

Comment: I did consider this at the start, is it IndexedDB with a Web SQL fallback, or Web SQL with an IndexedDB fallback? I think that was the reason I leaned towards IDBWrapper with the IndexedDBShim. I am a beginner with these web databases though. Thanks, I will definitely take another look :)

Comment: I've just looked at your todo list demo, it looks like you prioritise IndexedDB which seems good :) In that example though, it appears to be out-of-line keys as the keyPath is timeStamp and you generate that yourself, and store it manually on the 'data' object. So my question based on your library would be, if you used autoIncrementing inline keys, and you didn't store the timeStamp on the object manually, would Web SQL know which object to update? Also it looks like in Web SQL every time you refresh the demo makes a new store?

Comment: Just node, if you want to update auto generated key record, both `add` and `put` method return primary key. You put the primary key to the record value before you update next time.

Comment: @KyawTun, that looks very nice. May I ask why you don't have a Github repo too? I spent a lot of time looking for a good polyfill and I never came across yours until today (all the top results were from Github).

Comment: Oops, found it! https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db (only thing is it doesn't come up on searches about polyfills and shims)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue while updating the objects. Couldn't do that using inline keys. So, I switched to out-of-line keys to solve the problem. 
I am using the combination of [Jquery IndexedDB plugin](http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/) plugin and [IndexedDB Shim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) to support all the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The way I resolved this was to:

1. Always set the `keyPath` to be `"key"` when creating the IDBStore. This is to take into account the fact that the IndexedDB Shim was using the property called `key` to refer to the index of each record in the WebSQL database.
2. I had to add a clause in the IDBWrapper code:

   ```
     // cope with WebSQL implementation, keyPath must always be "key" for this to work.
     if (!cursor.primaryKey) {
       cursor.value.key = cursor.key;
     }
   ```

Into the `_getAllCursor` function as shown (line 682 for me):

```
_getAllCursor: function (getAllTransaction, store, onSuccess, onError) {
  var all = [],
      hasSuccess = false,
      result = null;

  getAllTransaction.oncomplete = function () {
    var callback = hasSuccess ? onSuccess : onError;
    callback(result);
  };
  getAllTransaction.onabort = onError;
  getAllTransaction.onerror = onError;

  var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();
  cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
      // cope with WebSQL implementation, keyPath must always be key for this to work.
      if (!cursor.primaryKey) {
        cursor.value.key = cursor.key;
      }
      all.push(cursor.value);
      cursor['continue']();
    }
    else {
      hasSuccess = true;
      result = all;
    }
  };
  cursorRequest.onError = onError;
},
```

Basically what this is doing is, if there is no primaryKey on cursor, from testing with Chrome and Safari, this seemed to be an indicator that the code was working within a WebSQL environment. There may be more solid ways of detecting a lack of IDB support, but this works well for me. So within the `if`, just set the 'key' property of the cursor onto the value so that when it ends up being saved to WebSQL it has the right index on there.

However because I don't have the time to test his library and changeover to it, and he was very helpful, I am going to give Kyaw Tun the benefit of the doubt and accept his answer, especially as it appears that IDBWrapper and IndexedDBShim (and JQuery IndexedDB plugin and IndexedDBShim, according to GemK) don't appear to work together when using inline keys. Arguably it is nicer to have 1 dependent library rather than 2.

**UPDATE**

I did run into problems further down the line with this approach, in one of those "how did this ever work?" scenarios.

Just as I was about to remove IndexedDBShim and IDBWrapper, and replace with ydn-db, I had another look in Safari.

As mentioned, I have no idea how this ever worked, but in

`IDBOjectStore.prototype.put` on line 1090 (for me) of IndexedDBShim.js, the key was undefined and then never used in an update.

So I had to add

```
if (key === undefined && value.key !== undefined) {
  key = value.key;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Really, just ignore this post now, looks like IDBShim is going to be fixed, I am sure that will be a better solution.
However, this solution does have another issue. The check against `cursor.primaryKey` isn't definitive, sometimes I have found it does contain the key value in there. So just set `cursor.value.key` anyway.

**UPDATE 3**

In case anyone has not heeded my earlier warning to ignore all this. If you set the key manually it will fail, silently in my case, because if the key is set and keypath also has a value, WebSQL cannot determine if you want inline keys (i.e. you defined keypath) or out-of-line keys (i.e. you actually provided a key value, so presumably you don't want to auto-increment). It is a misconception that to update the record you need to provide the key outside of the object value, as long as the object value you are saving has a property named after the keypath string, containing the correct key, that should be enough.

Saying this, why did I make the change detailed in the first UPDATE originally? Because on ocassion, duplicate records were being added instead of being updated.

The *real* problem was, for me on line 1003. The primary key is extracted from the object, and then evaluated using `!`. For me, in some browsers, the first key was being generated as `0`. This fails the evaluation and therefore WebSQL generates a new auto-increment key.

I changed:

```
var primaryKey = eval("value['" + props.keyPath + "']");
if (!primaryKey) {
    if (props.autoInc === "true") {
        getNextAutoIncKey();
    }
    else {
        idbModules.util.throwDOMException(0, "Data Error - Could not eval key from keyPath");
    }
}
else {
    callback(primaryKey);
}
```

To:

```
var primaryKey = eval("value['" + props.keyPath + "']");
if (primaryKey === undefined) {
    if (props.autoInc === "true") {
        getNextAutoIncKey();
    }
    else {
        idbModules.util.throwDOMException(0, "Data Error - Could not eval key from keyPath");
    }
}
else {
    callback(primaryKey);
}
```

Comment: No need to doubt. I consider very detail, not to make it just work and everything to follow Indexeddb spec. For detail polyfill implementations see http://dev.yathit.com/blog/indexeddb-polyfill.html

Comment: I found out the same kind of errors, this time in chrome for both pc and iOS. on the pc the autoincremented key starts from 1, but on Chrome for iOS starts from 0 and is not present in the object saved into the database. The same thing in Safari for iOS, the key starts from 0. I haven't tried IDBWrapper with nparashuram indexeddb shim, but I tried this [link](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js). I noticed the same problems, but I don't think it's the wrappers problem. The library above has nice features and is very well documented.Have you tried other indexeddb wrappers?

Comment: I use IDBWrapper. Yes I don't think you should rely on the key being 0, or more than 0, it seems to be browser specific.

Comment: See most recent update. I had to make a code change in IndexedDBShim to cope with keys that are generated from 0, making me unable to update records with a key of 0 because it was assumed that there was no key so a new auto-incremented key was required.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. I've patched the shim to include the autogenerated id in the record. I've added my patch to issue 122 at https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/issues/122